# How to print array in single_line?

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures, reverse

I am attempting to print a reversed array (list) of integers as a single line of space-separated numbers.

I've tried to use a for loop and printed each integer separately with a sep = ", " to remove the commas from the list. Should I use the remove() method as one alternative?

```
       n = int(input())
       arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

       for i in arr[::-1]:
         print(i, sep = ", ")
```

## Output

```
2
3
4
1
```

## Should be:

```
2 3 4 1
```

Suppose I inputted 4. The expected results should be the exact sequence in the output but in a single line.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, this is what you look for:

```
print(*reversed(arr))
```

If a comma separator is needed, you can write

```
print(*reversed(arr), sep=", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   for i in arr[::-1]:
     print(i, end = ", ")
```